# Changing Identity Online

Tags: cookies, ip

What can be done to change your identity completely online?

A website can track you by this information :

- IP Address
- Cookies

So if you changed these factors and connected to a website you would remian a different user form the last time you connected?

Is there really anything else that can be used from your connection that can map your identity?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It *might* be on-topic at [security.se].

Comment: Okay, thank you i will ask it there